# chrome extension to read post request data

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to read json of post request using Chrome Extension. So i have created a extension with following code:-

menifest.json file:-

```
{
  "name": "numera name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "numera",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
     "activeTab",
     "tabs"
   ]
}
```

contentScript.js

```
function interceptData() {


var xhrOverrideScript = document.createElement('script');
  xhrOverrideScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  xhrOverrideScript.innerHTML = '
  (function() {
    var XHR = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;
    var send = XHR.send;
    var open = XHR.open;
    XHR.open = function(method, url) {
        this.url = url; // the request url
        return open.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    XHR.send = function() {
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
            if (this.url.includes('WaitForResponsesData')) {
                var dataDOMElement = document.createElement('div');
                dataDOMElement.id = '__interceptedData';
                dataDOMElement.innerText = this.response;
                console.log(this.response);
                dataDOMElement.style.height = 0;
                //dataDOMElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
                document.body.appendChild(dataDOMElement);
            }               
        });
        return send.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  })();'
  document.head.prepend(xhrOverrideScript);
}
function checkForDOM() {
  if (document.body && document.head) {
    interceptData();
  } else {
    requestIdleCallback(checkForDOM);
  }
}
requestIdleCallback(checkForDOM);

function scrapeData() {
    var responseContainingEle = document.getElementById('__interceptedData');
    if (responseContainingEle) {
        var response = JSON.parse(responseContainingEle.innerHTML);
    } else {
        requestIdleCallback(scrapeData);
    }
}
requestIdleCallback(scrapeData);
```

But I am not sure why this code is not working i have added console log and alert as well not no luck, 
Also i have tried to search __interceptedData ID in page HTML but that is also not there.

I followed this URL https://medium.com/better-programming/chrome-extension-intercepting-and-reading-the-body-of-http-requests-dd9ebdf2348b

please help me out from this

Comment: 1) `"*://WaitForResponsesData/*"` should be a valid URL pattern or `"<all_urls>"`, 2) the innerHTML string is not closed, you're missing another \` after `})();`

Comment: @wOxxOm so you mean it should be like  "matches": ["www.test.com/WaitForResponsesData/"], please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: It depends on the actual URL. See also the documentation for [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

Comment: added as you suggested but where i can see its output ?

Comment: even console log is also not working. and how i get know its functions are working or not

Comment: I don't know what you added and what is the actual URL of the tab so I can't really help. Also, after you edit the scripts you need to reload the extension on `chrome://extensions` page and reload the site tab.

Comment: You may want to find a different tutorial. Or use a dedicated library like [xhook](https://github.com/jpillora/xhook).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203810/discussion-between-er-kk-chopra-and-woxxom).

Comment: `xhrOverrideScript.innerHTML = '';` assigns an empty string, it's not what you need here. Please read my first comment above.

Comment: ok got it, tried with that still its not working

Comment: Well, you'll need to debug it in devtools. See tutorials on "how to debug content scripts in Chrome". As for the script element code, to debug it you can add `debugger;` statement. And don't forget to reload the extension. Also, this entire code doesn't do anything useful because `response` isn't used anywhere. Actually the entire solution is terrible so I suggest you find a better tutorial or just use `xhook` library. You should be able to find better examples easily, here's one on StackOverflow: [Chrome extension to read HTTP response](//stackoverflow.com/a/48134114)